# UDK: BSP from Brush-CSG Add cannot be deleted

Tags: unreal, udk, binary-space-partitioning

Once a BSP has been created using Brush-CSG add it cannot be deleted.

Del-DELETE from the keyboard yields no effect. Right click-cut yields no effect.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

*SOLVED*
Brush-CSG Subtract deletes everything